# How to to make a piece of HTML in blogger only visible to admins?

Tags: html, blogger

I want to add a control panel to my blog, I found this [here](https://helplogger.blogspot.com/2014/01/add-admin-control-panel-in-blogger.html):

```
<span class='item-control blog-admin'>
<style>
.control-panel ul{z-index: 20; position: absolute; margin: 0px auto; background-color: #F6F6F6; width: 100%; }
.control-panel ul li{display: inline-block; float: left; padding: 7px 0px;}
.control-panel ul li a {color:#686868;padding: 7px 15px;border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;font-weight: bold;font-size: 13px;}
.control-panel a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#FC8F44;}
</style>
<div class='control-panel'>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.blogger.com/home'>My Blogs</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#editor/src=sidebar&quot;' rel='nofollow'>New Post</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#editor/target=page&quot;' rel='nofollow'>New Page</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#posts&quot;' rel='nofollow'>All Posts</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#comments&quot;' rel='nofollow'>Comments</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#pageelements&quot;' rel='nofollow'>Layout</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#templatehtml&quot;' rel='nofollow'>Edit HTML</a></li>
<li><a href='#' onclick='location.reload(true); return false;'>Refresh</a></li>
<li><a href='/' target='_blank'>New Tab</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#basicsettings&quot;' rel='nofollow'>Settings</a></li>
<li><a expr:href='&quot;http://www.blogger.com/blogger.g?blogID=&quot; + data:blog.blogId + &quot;#overviewstats&quot;' rel='nofollow'>Stats</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.blogger.com/logout.g'>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</span>
```

I added it under the `body` of my blog's theme but the gadget is always hidden, is there a way to make it only visible to admin?

Comment: Could you share the URL of the blog where the above code is not working?

Comment: @PrayagVerma this: https://buildsucceeded.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For v2 templates**, The above code should work as expected because of the presence of `blog-admin` class on the `span` tag. This element has CSS set to `display:block` **only** when an admin visits the blog. This is achieved using the following dynamic CSS file which Blogger automatically adds to every blog (The authorization for finding out whether the visitor is admin or not happens behind the scenes and we don't have to worry about that).

```
https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=XXXXX&amp;zx=XXXXX
```

In certain cases, template creators prevent loading this dynamic CSS file (likely because this CSS file is never cached and there is certainly a speed benefit even if its minimal) by replacing -

```
</head>
```

with

```html
&lt;!-- 
</head>
--&gt; &lt;/head&gt;
```

In those cases, you will have to undo the steps to make sure that the dynamic CSS gets loaded.

---

**For v3 themes**, the quick editing feature is not supported by default.

[image: quick editing not supported]

Hence manually adding the dynamic CSS to the code will make things work -

```
<link href='https://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=6752007275128684588&amp;zx=2f99e9cb-69f3-46cb-b0cf-85ae799dfa91' rel='stylesheet'/>
```

- `targetBlogID` query parameter needs to be set to your BlogID
- `zx` query parameter is an auto-generated parameter (and likely responsible for authorization)

Comment: still the same, you can see the blog now with changes you've suggested

Comment: @mshwf I have edited the answer and added the procedure for v3 themes (Your blog uses those). Try using the `zx` parameter that I have shared and see if things work out or not